# How to filter for oldest value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of objects with names and dates.

Let's say kids and birthdays

```
Lukas M. 14.1.2000
Lukas B. 14.2.2000
Lukas A. 15.1.2000
Lukas C. 30.1.2000
Max A. 15.1.2000
Max B. 15.2.2000
Max C. 16.1.2000
Max D. 31.1.2000
```

And i would like to find out, which Lukas and which Max is the youngest in excel.
First name and last name are different columns.

Obviously there are much more values than just the above mentionned.

(I don't really need to filter for kids birthdays, but my values change constantly -the "names" as well as the "birthdays")

How do I get the following result:

```
Lukas 14.2.2000
Max 15.2.2000
```

I use excel 2013

Comment: Can you define what data is in which column? Are these three columns of data for example? First name, last name and birthday? Can you also include what version of Excel you got? Excel O365 got a nice new `FILTER` function for example. Btw, currently there is ***no*** way in your result to destinguish between which Lukas and Max since you left out lastnames.

Comment: Use `MIN()` this will help you https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3333-excel-find-earliest-date-based-on-criteria.html

Comment: i dont care which lukas or max I just care about the firstname (we can disregard the lastname column), that was just for an easier explenation

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Office365` Then try below.
First you need to extract unique values from Kids column. Use `UNIQUE()` function.

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A8)
```

Then need to find `MAX()` from Birthday column based on names. Use `MAXIFS()` function.

```
=MAXIFS($C$1:$C$8,$A$1:$A$8,E2#)
```

[image]

Comment: If you do not have `OFFICE365` then need combination of few formulas.

Comment: See what happens if you use an `#` right behind `E2` as the third parameter =)

Comment: @JvdV That is wonder of `OFFICE365`. I like it. It will spill automatically till last data cell of `E Column`. Thanks for pointing.